# Trying to publish messages to rabbit mq server

Tags: python, rabbitmq

This isn't working

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('user', 'user')

parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('rabbitmqqa2.server.com',
                                   15672,
                                   '/',
                                   credentials)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='zabbix-mail')

message = 'Python Queue - Message Sent from sender.py {N|T}'

channel.basic_publish(exchange='zabbix',
                      routing_key='zabbix-mail-route',
                      body=message)
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")

connection.close()
```

Comment: are you getting any error while running it ?

Comment: "It's not working". Is not a question. Neither is "what's wrong?". That is something that you should tell us.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct port that your rabbitmq server is actually running on?  15672 is typically the web-based management port.  The default port that the message queue is on is 5672.

Comment: you've declared your queue, but I do not see any exchange declaration for zabbix, nor a binding between it and your declared queue, Can you confirm those are present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You've not mentioned error, I can advise you to check following points.

1. is rabbitmq working on connected machine ?
2. you are using port 15672 but default port for sending message is 5672
3. default credentials (username,password) of rabbitmq is "guest" and "guest" respectively.
4. Since you are not declaring exchange or binding to queue, you should manually make them from rabbitmq panel ( by default running on 15672)